# api returns messy data. How to convert to an array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an api call from dark skies that returns data as shown:

```
Array ( [0] => {"latitude":42.337,"longitude":-70.951589,"timezone":"America/New_York","hourly":{"summary":"Rain until tonight.","icon":"rain","data":[{"time":1616968800,"summary":"Rain","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0659,"precipProbability":0.66,"precipType":"rain","temperature":51.01,"apparentTemperature":51.01,"dewPoint":49.37,"humidity":0.94,"pressure":998.7,"windSpeed":15.22,"windGust":30.64,"windBearing":172,"cloudCover":1,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":2.07,"ozone":329.1},{"time":1616972400,"summary":"Possible Light Rain","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0263,"precipProbability":0.53,"precipType":"rain","temperature":53.33,"apparentTemperature":53.33,"dewPoint":50.86,"humidity":0.91,"pressure":997.2,"windSpeed":15.07,"windGust":34.46,"windBearing":196,"cloudCover":0.99,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":3.242,"ozone":332.5},{"time":1616976000,"summary":"Possible Light Rain","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0262,"precipProbability":0.51,"precipType":"rain","temperature":54.85,"apparentTemperature":54.85,"dewPoint":52.19,"humidity":0.91,"pressure":996.3,"windSpeed":15.46,"windGust":36.98,"windBearing":202,"cloudCover":1,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":7.329,"ozone":336.3},{"time":1616979600,"summary":"Possible Light Rain","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0281,"precipProbability":0.55,"precipType":"rain","temperature":56.53,"apparentTemperature":56.53,"dewPoint":53.96,"humidity":0.91,"pressure":995.5,"windSpeed":16.51,"windGust":38.82,"windBearing":207,"cloudCover":1,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":4.65,"ozone":338.7},{"time":1616983200,"summary":"Rain","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0385,"precipProbability":0.63,"precipType":"rain","temperature":57.18,"apparentTemperature":57.18,"dewPoint":54.59,"humidity":0.91,"pressure":994.9,"windSpeed":16.19,"windGust":35.72,"windBearing":235,"cloudCover":1,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":9.149,"ozone":341.9},{"time":1616986800,"summary":"Rain","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0938,"precipProbability":0.8,"precipType":"rain","temperature":56.45,"apparentTemperature":56.45,"dewPoint":52.95,"humidity":0.88,"pressure":995.3,"windSpeed":14.9,"windGust":31.54,"windBearing":260,"cloudCover":1,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":8.05,"ozone":344.8},{"time":1616990400,"summary":"Rain","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0635,"precipProbability":0.75,"precipType":"rain","temperature":54.37,"apparentTemperature":54.37,"dewPoint":49.05,"humidity":0.82,"pressure":995.7,"windSpeed":13.13,"windGust":28.63,"windBearing":245,"cloudCover":1,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":347.9},{"time":1616994000,"summary":"Rain","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0591,"precipProbability":0.69,"precipType":"rain","temperature":52.74,"apparentTemperature":52.74,"dewPoint":46.32,"humidity":0.79,"pressure":995.8,"windSpeed":13.41,"windGust":27.31,"windBearing":260,"cloudCover":0.99,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":355.4},{"time":1616997600,"summary":"Rain","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0428,"precipProbability":0.55,"precipType":"rain","temperature":50.68,"apparentTemperature":50.68,"dewPoint":43.09,"humidity":0.75,"pressure":996.1,"windSpeed":14.22,"windGust":28.9,"windBearing":257,"cloudCover":0.96,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":369.5},{"time":1617001200,"summary":"Possible Light Rain","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0346,"precipProbability":0.32,"precipType":"rain","temperature":49.72,"apparentTemperature":44,"dewPoint":40.71,"humidity":0.71,"pressure":996.4,"windSpeed":16.2,"windGust":33.27,"windBearing":272,"cloudCover":0.92,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":371.1},{"time":1617004800,"summary":"Mostly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-night","precipIntensity":0.0034,"precipProbability":0.14,"precipType":"rain","temperature":48.09,"apparentTemperature":41.5,"dewPoint":38.25,"humidity":0.69,"pressure":996.7,"windSpeed":18.05,"windGust":36.02,"windBearing":257,"cloudCover":0.71,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":386.4},{"time":1617008400,"summary":"Windy and Partly Cloudy","icon":"wind","precipIntensity":0.0013,"precipProbability":0.09,"precipType":"rain","temperature":46.03,"apparentTemperature":38.28,"dewPoint":35.67,"humidity":0.67,"pressure":997.2,"windSpeed":20.51,"windGust":39.58,"windBearing":261,"cloudCover":0.43,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":399.7},{"time":1617012000,"summary":"Windy and Partly Cloudy","icon":"wind","precipIntensity":0.0011,"precipProbability":0.07,"precipType":"rain","temperature":43.86,"apparentTemperature":35.16,"dewPoint":33.77,"humidity":0.67,"pressure":998.2,"windSpeed":21.81,"windGust":42.09,"windBearing":238,"cloudCover":0.35,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":408.5},{"time":1617015600,"summary":"Windy and Partly Cloudy","icon":"wind","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":42.2,"apparentTemperature":32.66,"dewPoint":31.89,"humidity":0.67,"pressure":999.6,"windSpeed":23.3,"windGust":42.52,"windBearing":300,"cloudCover":0.5,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":413.4},{"time":1617019200,"summary":"Windy and Partly Cloudy","icon":"wind","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":41.32,"apparentTemperature":31.37,"dewPoint":30.71,"humidity":0.66,"pressure":1001.5,"windSpeed":23.87,"windGust":42.91,"windBearing":270,"cloudCover":0.43,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":418.1},{"time":1617022800,"summary":"Windy and Partly Cloudy","icon":"wind","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":41.72,"apparentTemperature":31.89,"dewPoint":30.27,"humidity":0.64,"pressure":1002.7,"windSpeed":23.91,"windGust":43.93,"windBearing":229,"cloudCover":0.41,"uvIndex":1,"visibility":10,"ozone":420.2},{"time":1617026400,"summary":"Windy and Partly Cloudy","icon":"wind","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":42.74,"apparentTemperature":33.29,"dewPoint":29.96,"humidity":0.6,"pressure":1003.8,"windSpeed":23.75,"windGust":43.99,"windBearing":323,"cloudCover":0.35,"uvIndex":2,"visibility":10,"ozone":425},{"time":1617030000,"summary":"Windy and Partly Cloudy","icon":"wind","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":43.87,"apparentTemperature":34.87,"dewPoint":29.1,"humidity":0.56,"pressure":1005.1,"windSpeed":23.34,"windGust":43.12,"windBearing":279,"cloudCover":0.34,"uvIndex":3,"visibility":10,"ozone":424.2},{"time":1617033600,"summary":"Windy","icon":"wind","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":44.75,"apparentTemperature":36.1,"dewPoint":28.65,"humidity":0.53,"pressure":1006.4,"windSpeed":23,"windGust":41.05,"windBearing":275,"cloudCover":0.21,"uvIndex":4,"visibility":10,"ozone":424.4},{"time":1617037200,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":45.93,"apparentTemperature":37.74,"dewPoint":27.45,"humidity":0.48,"pressure":1007.8,"windSpeed":22.61,"windGust":38.93,"windBearing":278,"cloudCover":0.17,"uvIndex":4,"visibility":10,"ozone":425.8},{"time":1617040800,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":47.23,"apparentTemperature":39.59,"dewPoint":25.54,"humidity":0.42,"pressure":1009.5,"windSpeed":21.96,"windGust":36.83,"windBearing":288,"cloudCover":0.12,"uvIndex":4,"visibility":10,"ozone":430.4},{"time":1617044400,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":48.02,"apparentTemperature":40.82,"dewPoint":22.69,"humidity":0.37,"pressure":1010.7,"windSpeed":20.94,"windGust":35.26,"windBearing":292,"cloudCover":0.02,"uvIndex":3,"visibility":10,"ozone":427.7},{"time":1617048000,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":48.35,"apparentTemperature":41.48,"dewPoint":20.24,"humidity":0.33,"pressure":1012.2,"windSpeed":19.76,"windGust":34.55,"windBearing":296,"cloudCover":0.02,"uvIndex":2,"visibility":10,"ozone":423.5},{"time":1617051600,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":48.07,"apparentTemperature":41.42,"dewPoint":19.28,"humidity":0.32,"pressure":1013.9,"windSpeed":18.29,"windGust":33.4,"windBearing":299,"cloudCover":0.02,"uvIndex":1,"visibility":10,"ozone":417.6},{"time":1617055200,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":47.04,"apparentTemperature":40.48,"dewPoint":18.85,"humidity":0.32,"pressure":1015.7,"windSpeed":16.48,"windGust":32.14,"windBearing":298,"cloudCover":0.02,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":410.5},{"time":1617058800,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":45.48,"apparentTemperature":38.93,"dewPoint":18.44,"humidity":0.34,"pressure":1017.6,"windSpeed":14.7,"windGust":30.35,"windBearing":297,"cloudCover":0.02,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":405.2},{"time":1617062400,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":44.57,"apparentTemperature":38.23,"dewPoint":18.68,"humidity":0.35,"pressure":1019.8,"windSpeed":13.13,"windGust":28.3,"windBearing":297,"cloudCover":0,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":386.7},{"time":1617066000,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":43.55,"apparentTemperature":37.34,"dewPoint":18.82,"humidity":0.37,"pressure":1021.4,"windSpeed":11.88,"windGust":26.71,"windBearing":296,"cloudCover":0,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":383.1},{"time":1617069600,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":42.55,"apparentTemperature":36.45,"dewPoint":18.74,"humidity":0.38,"pressure":1022.7,"windSpeed":10.89,"windGust":24.83,"windBearing":294,"cloudCover":0,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":381.3},{"time":1617073200,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":41.59,"apparentTemperature":35.68,"dewPoint":18.43,"humidity":0.39,"pressure":1023.8,"windSpeed":9.83,"windGust":22.68,"windBearing":293,"cloudCover":0,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":377.2},{"time":1617076800,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":40.62,"apparentTemperature":34.99,"dewPoint":18.47,"humidity":0.41,"pressure":1024.4,"windSpeed":8.71,"windGust":20.42,"windBearing":296,"cloudCover":0,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":372.9},{"time":1617080400,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":39.59,"apparentTemperature":34.24,"dewPoint":18.72,"humidity":0.43,"pressure":1025.1,"windSpeed":7.71,"windGust":18.16,"windBearing":275,"cloudCover":0,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":367.9},{"time":1617084000,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":38.54,"apparentTemperature":33.49,"dewPoint":19.08,"humidity":0.45,"pressure":1025.4,"windSpeed":6.81,"windGust":15.13,"windBearing":287,"cloudCover":0.02,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":359.3},{"time":1617087600,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":37.52,"apparentTemperature":32.69,"dewPoint":19.2,"humidity":0.47,"pressure":1026,"windSpeed":6.17,"windGust":12.9,"windBearing":326,"cloudCover":0.03,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":353.7},{"time":1617091200,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":36.45,"apparentTemperature":31.56,"dewPoint":19.6,"humidity":0.5,"pressure":1026.8,"windSpeed":5.95,"windGust":12.48,"windBearing":212,"cloudCover":0.02,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":351.4},{"time":1617094800,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":35.68,"apparentTemperature":30.91,"dewPoint":20,"humidity":0.53,"pressure":1027.6,"windSpeed":5.61,"windGust":11.89,"windBearing":253,"cloudCover":0.01,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":349.2},{"time":1617098400,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":35.09,"apparentTemperature":30.39,"dewPoint":20.28,"humidity":0.54,"pressure":1028.1,"windSpeed":5.38,"windGust":11.72,"windBearing":265,"cloudCover":0.01,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":345.6},{"time":1617102000,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":35.21,"apparentTemperature":30.69,"dewPoint":20.67,"humidity":0.55,"pressure":1028.7,"windSpeed":5.19,"windGust":11.11,"windBearing":245,"cloudCover":0.01,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":341.4},{"time":1617105600,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":36.88,"apparentTemperature":32.89,"dewPoint":21.23,"humidity":0.53,"pressure":1029.6,"windSpeed":4.9,"windGust":8.38,"windBearing":229,"cloudCover":0.05,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":337.7},{"time":1617109200,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":39.87,"apparentTemperature":35.99,"dewPoint":21.09,"humidity":0.47,"pressure":1029.9,"windSpeed":5.44,"windGust":9,"windBearing":216,"cloudCover":0.04,"uvIndex":2,"visibility":10,"ozone":336.2},{"time":1617112800,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":43.3,"apparentTemperature":39.47,"dewPoint":21.12,"humidity":0.41,"pressure":1029.8,"windSpeed":6.37,"windGust":10.62,"windBearing":192,"cloudCover":0.02,"uvIndex":3,"visibility":10,"ozone":337.1},{"time":1617116400,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":46.47,"apparentTemperature":42.7,"dewPoint":20.86,"humidity":0.36,"pressure":1029.4,"windSpeed":7.49,"windGust":11.99,"windBearing":184,"cloudCover":0.01,"uvIndex":5,"visibility":10,"ozone":339.7},{"time":1617120000,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":49.16,"apparentTemperature":45.53,"dewPoint":22.48,"humidity":0.35,"pressure":1028.9,"windSpeed":8.52,"windGust":13.06,"windBearing":182,"cloudCover":0,"uvIndex":6,"visibility":10,"ozone":334.3},{"time":1617123600,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":51.86,"apparentTemperature":51.86,"dewPoint":24.33,"humidity":0.34,"pressure":1028.7,"windSpeed":9.6,"windGust":14.24,"windBearing":184,"cloudCover":0,"uvIndex":6,"visibility":10,"ozone":331.9},{"time":1617127200,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":54.05,"apparentTemperature":54.05,"dewPoint":26.09,"humidity":0.34,"pressure":1028.3,"windSpeed":10.88,"windGust":15.61,"windBearing":184,"cloudCover":0.01,"uvIndex":5,"visibility":10,"ozone":329.5},{"time":1617130800,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":55.34,"apparentTemperature":55.34,"dewPoint":26.99,"humidity":0.33,"pressure":1027.6,"windSpeed":12.12,"windGust":17.42,"windBearing":189,"cloudCover":0.03,"uvIndex":4,"visibility":10,"ozone":326.1},{"time":1617134400,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":55.49,"apparentTemperature":55.49,"dewPoint":27.83,"humidity":0.34,"pressure":1026.8,"windSpeed":13,"windGust":19.07,"windBearing":193,"cloudCover":0.05,"uvIndex":3,"visibility":10,"ozone":324.8},{"time":1617138000,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":54.56,"apparentTemperature":54.56,"dewPoint":28.77,"humidity":0.37,"pressure":1026.2,"windSpeed":13.46,"windGust":20.83,"windBearing":197,"cloudCover":0.06,"uvIndex":1,"visibility":10,"ozone":326.2},{"time":1617141600,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":52.82,"apparentTemperature":52.82,"dewPoint":29.61,"humidity":0.41,"pressure":1026.1,"windSpeed":13.3,"windGust":23.12,"windBearing":197,"cloudCover":0.07,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":327}]},"offset":-4} )
```

so it comes back as an array but it's really confusing to work with. I was able to strip out the " with:

```
$dark = str_replace('"','',$darkRaw);
```

which gives me:

```
Array ( [0] => {latitude:42.337,longitude:-70.951589,timezone:America/New_York,hourly:{summary:Rain until tonight.,icon:rain,data:[{time:1616968800,summary:Rain,icon:rain,precipIntensity:0.0659,precipProbability:0.66,precipType:rain,temperature:51.01,apparentTemperature:51.01,dewPoint:49.37,humidity:0.94,pressure:998.7,windSpeed:15.22,windGust:30.64,windBearing:172,cloudCover:1,uvIndex:0,visibility:2.07,ozone:329.1},{time:1616972400,summary:Possible Light Rain,icon:rain,precipIntensity:0.0263,precipProbability:0.53,precipType:rain,temperature:53.33,apparentTemperature:53.33,dewPoint:50.86,humidity:0.91,pressure:997.2,windSpeed:15.07,windGust:34.46,windBearing:196,cloudCover:0.99,uvIndex:0,visibility:3.242,ozone:332.5},{time:1616976000,summary:Possible Light Rain,icon:rain,precipIntensity:0.0262,precipProbability:0.51,precipType:rain,temperature:54.85,apparentTemperature:54.85,dewPoint:52.19,humidity:0.91,pressure:996.3,windSpeed:15.46,windGust:36.98,windBearing:202,cloudCover:1,uvIndex:0,visibility:7.329,ozone:336.3},{time:1616979600,summary:Possible Light Rain,icon:rain,precipIntensity:0.0281,precipProbability:0.55,precipType:rain,temperature:56.53,apparentTemperature:56.53,dewPoint:53.96,humidity:0.91,pressure:995.5,windSpeed:16.51,windGust:38.82,windBearing:207,cloudCover:1,uvIndex:0,visibility:4.65,ozone:338.7},{time:1616983200,summary:Rain,icon:rain,precipIntensity:0.0385,precipProbability:0.63,precipType:rain,temperature:57.18,apparentTemperature:57.18,dewPoint:54.59,humidity:0.91,pressure:994.9,windSpeed:16.19,windGust:35.72,windBearing:235,cloudCover:1,uvIndex:0,visibility:9.149,ozone:341.9},{time:1616986800,summary:Rain,icon:rain,precipIntensity:0.0938,precipProbability:0.8,precipType:rain,temperature:56.45,apparentTemperature:56.45,dewPoint:52.95,humidity:0.88,pressure:995.3,windSpeed:14.9,windGust:31.54,windBearing:260,cloudCover:1,uvIndex:0,visibility:8.05,ozone:344.8},{time:1616990400,summary:Rain,icon:rain,precipIntensity:0.0635,precipProbability:0.75,precipType:rain,temperature:54.37,apparentTemperature:54.37,dewPoint:49.05,humidity:0.82,pressure:995.7,windSpeed:13.13,windGust:28.63,windBearing:245,cloudCover:1,uvIndex:0,visibility:10,ozone:347.9},{time:1616994000,summary:Rain,icon:rain,precipIntensity:0.0591,precipProbability:0.69,precipType:rain,temperature:52.73,apparentTemperature:52.73,dewPoint:46.32,humidity:0.79,pressure:995.8,windSpeed:13.41,windGust:27.31,windBearing:260,cloudCover:0.99,uvIndex:0,visibility:10,ozone:355.4},{time:1616997600,summary:Rain,icon:rain,precipIntensity:0.0428,precipProbability:0.55,precipType:rain,temperature:50.68,apparentTemperature:50.68,dewPoint:43.09,humidity:0.75,pressure:996.1,windSpeed:14.22,windGust:28.9,windBearing:257,cloudCover:0.96,uvIndex:0,visibility:10,ozone:369.5},{time:1617001200,summary:Possible Light Rain,icon:rain,precipIntensity:0.0346,precipProbability:0.32,precipType:rain,temperature:49.71,apparentTemperature:44,dewPoint:40.71,humidity:0.71,pressure:996.4,windSpeed:16.2,windGust:33.27,windBearing:272,cloudCover:0.92,uvIndex:0,visibility:10,ozone:371.1},{time:1617004800,summary:Mostly Cloudy,icon:partly-cloudy-night,precipIntensity:0.0034,precipProbability:0.14,precipType:rain,temperature:48.09,apparentTemperature:41.49,dewPoint:38.25,humidity:0.69,pressure:996.7,windSpeed:18.05,windGust:36.02,windBearing:257,cloudCover:0.71,uvIndex:0,visibility:10,ozone:386.4},{time:1617008400,summary:Windy and Partly Cloudy,icon:wind,precipIntensity:0.0013,precipProbability:0.09,precipType:rain,temperature:46.02,apparentTemperature:38.28,dewPoint:35.67,humidity:0.67,pressure:997.2,windSpeed:20.51,windGust:39.58,windBearing:261,cloudCover:0.43,uvIndex:0,visibility:10,ozone:399.7},{time:1617012000,summary:Windy and Partly Cloudy,icon:wind,precipIntensity:0.0011,precipProbability:0.07,precipType:rain,temperature:43.86,apparentTemperature:35.16,dewPoint:33.76,humidity:0.67,pressure:998.2,windSpeed:21.81,windGust:42.09,windBearing:238,cloudCover:0.35,uvIndex:0,visibility:10,ozone:408.5},{time:1617015600,summary:Windy and Partly Cloudy,icon:wind,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:42.2,apparentTemperature:32.65,dewPoint:31.88,humidity:0.67,pressure:999.6,windSpeed:23.3,windGust:42.52,windBearing:300,cloudCover:0.5,uvIndex:0,visibility:10,ozone:413.4},{time:1617019200,summary:Windy and Partly Cloudy,icon:wind,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:41.31,apparentTemperature:31.36,dewPoint:30.7,humidity:0.66,pressure:1001.5,windSpeed:23.87,windGust:42.91,windBearing:270,cloudCover:0.43,uvIndex:0,visibility:10,ozone:418.1},{time:1617022800,summary:Windy and Partly Cloudy,icon:wind,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:41.85,apparentTemperature:32.07,dewPoint:30.26,humidity:0.63,pressure:1002.9,windSpeed:23.91,windGust:43.98,windBearing:229,cloudCover:0.42,uvIndex:1,visibility:10,ozone:420.1},{time:1617026400,summary:Windy and Partly Cloudy,icon:wind,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:42.89,apparentTemperature:33.5,dewPoint:29.96,humidity:0.6,pressure:1004,windSpeed:23.72,windGust:44.02,windBearing:323,cloudCover:0.32,uvIndex:2,visibility:10,ozone:425},{time:1617030000,summary:Windy,icon:wind,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:43.92,apparentTemperature:34.94,dewPoint:29.1,humidity:0.56,pressure:1005.3,windSpeed:23.34,windGust:43.15,windBearing:279,cloudCover:0.26,uvIndex:3,visibility:10,ozone:424.2},{time:1617033600,summary:Windy,icon:wind,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:44.73,apparentTemperature:36.07,dewPoint:28.65,humidity:0.53,pressure:1006.7,windSpeed:23,windGust:41.05,windBearing:275,cloudCover:0.22,uvIndex:4,visibility:10,ozone:424.3},{time:1617037200,summary:Clear,icon:clear-day,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:45.93,apparentTemperature:37.75,dewPoint:27.45,humidity:0.48,pressure:1008.1,windSpeed:22.61,windGust:38.93,windBearing:278,cloudCover:0.15,uvIndex:4,visibility:10,ozone:425.7},{time:1617040800,summary:Clear,icon:clear-day,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:47.22,apparentTemperature:39.58,dewPoint:25.54,humidity:0.42,pressure:1009.8,windSpeed:21.96,windGust:36.83,windBearing:288,cloudCover:0.12,uvIndex:4,visibility:10,ozone:430.3},{time:1617044400,summary:Clear,icon:clear-day,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:48.09,apparentTemperature:40.91,dewPoint:22.67,humidity:0.36,pressure:1010.9,windSpeed:20.94,windGust:35.26,windBearing:292,cloudCover:0.01,uvIndex:3,visibility:10,ozone:427.6},{time:1617048000,summary:Clear,icon:clear-day,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:48.41,apparentTemperature:41.56,dewPoint:20.2,humidity:0.32,pressure:1012.4,windSpeed:19.76,windGust:34.53,windBearing:296,cloudCover:0.02,uvIndex:2,visibility:10,ozone:423.4},{time:1617051600,summary:Clear,icon:clear-day,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:48.02,apparentTemperature:41.35,dewPoint:19.29,humidity:0.32,pressure:1014.1,windSpeed:18.29,windGust:33.39,windBearing:299,cloudCover:0.02,uvIndex:1,visibility:10,ozone:417.5},{time:1617055200,summary:Clear,icon:clear-day,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:46.94,apparentTemperature:40.35,dewPoint:18.84,humidity:0.32,pressure:1015.9,windSpeed:16.48,windGust:32.14,windBearing:298,cloudCover:0.02,uvIndex:0,visibility:10,ozone:410.4},{time:1617058800,summary:Clear,icon:clear-day,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:45.39,apparentTemperature:38.82,dewPoint:18.45,humidity:0.34,pressure:1017.8,windSpeed:14.71,windGust:30.31,windBearing:297,cloudCover:0.02,uvIndex:0,visibility:10,ozone:405.1},{time:1617062400,summary:Clear,icon:clear-night,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:44.47,apparentTemperature:38.1,dewPoint:18.71,humidity:0.35,pressure:1020,windSpeed:13.15,windGust:28.25,windBearing:297,cloudCover:0,uvIndex:0,visibility:10,ozone:386.6},{time:1617066000,summary:Clear,icon:clear-night,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:43.49,apparentTemperature:37.26,dewPoint:18.83,humidity:0.37,pressure:1021.6,windSpeed:11.9,windGust:26.67,windBearing:296,cloudCover:0,uvIndex:0,visibility:10,ozone:383.1},{time:1617069600,summary:Clear,icon:clear-night,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:42.51,apparentTemperature:36.41,dewPoint:18.74,humidity:0.38,pressure:1022.8,windSpeed:10.89,windGust:24.79,windBearing:294,cloudCover:0,uvIndex:0,visibility:10,ozone:381.3},{time:1617073200,summary:Clear,icon:clear-night,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:41.54,apparentTemperature:35.62,dewPoint:18.43,humidity:0.39,pressure:1023.8,windSpeed:9.83,windGust:22.66,windBearing:293,cloudCover:0,uvIndex:0,visibility:10,ozone:377.2},{time:1617076800,summary:Clear,icon:clear-night,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:40.58,apparentTemperature:34.94,dewPoint:18.46,humidity:0.41,pressure:1024.4,windSpeed:8.71,windGust:20.4,windBearing:295,cloudCover:0,uvIndex:0,visibility:10,ozone:372.9},{time:1617080400,summary:Clear,icon:clear-night,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:39.56,apparentTemperature:34.21,dewPoint:18.71,humidity:0.43,pressure:1025.1,windSpeed:7.7,windGust:18.16,windBearing:275,cloudCover:0,uvIndex:0,visibility:10,ozone:367.8},{time:1617084000,summary:Clear,icon:clear-night,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:38.49,apparentTemperature:33.43,dewPoint:19.07,humidity:0.45,pressure:1025.4,windSpeed:6.81,windGust:15.12,windBearing:287,cloudCover:0.02,uvIndex:0,visibility:10,ozone:359.3},{time:1617087600,summary:Clear,icon:clear-night,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:37.52,apparentTemperature:32.69,dewPoint:19.19,humidity:0.47,pressure:1026,windSpeed:6.16,windGust:12.89,windBearing:325,cloudCover:0.03,uvIndex:0,visibility:10,ozone:353.7},{time:1617091200,summary:Clear,icon:clear-night,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:36.42,apparentTemperature:31.53,dewPoint:19.58,humidity:0.5,pressure:1026.8,windSpeed:5.95,windGust:12.48,windBearing:212,cloudCover:0.02,uvIndex:0,visibility:10,ozone:351.4},{time:1617094800,summary:Clear,icon:clear-night,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:35.67,apparentTemperature:30.89,dewPoint:19.99,humidity:0.53,pressure:1027.5,windSpeed:5.61,windGust:11.89,windBearing:253,cloudCover:0.01,uvIndex:0,visibility:10,ozone:349.2},{time:1617098400,summary:Clear,icon:clear-night,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:35.1,apparentTemperature:30.4,dewPoint:20.3,humidity:0.54,pressure:1028,windSpeed:5.38,windGust:11.72,windBearing:265,cloudCover:0.01,uvIndex:0,visibility:10,ozone:345.6},{time:1617102000,summary:Clear,icon:clear-day,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:35.2,apparentTemperature:30.68,dewPoint:20.66,humidity:0.55,pressure:1028.7,windSpeed:5.19,windGust:11.11,windBearing:245,cloudCover:0.01,uvIndex:0,visibility:10,ozone:341.4},{time:1617105600,summary:Clear,icon:clear-day,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:36.87,apparentTemperature:32.88,dewPoint:21.22,humidity:0.53,pressure:1029.5,windSpeed:4.9,windGust:8.38,windBearing:229,cloudCover:0.05,uvIndex:0,visibility:10,ozone:337.7},{time:1617109200,summary:Clear,icon:clear-day,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:39.91,apparentTemperature:36.04,dewPoint:21.08,humidity:0.47,pressure:1029.9,windSpeed:5.44,windGust:9,windBearing:216,cloudCover:0.04,uvIndex:2,visibility:10,ozone:336.2},{time:1617112800,summary:Clear,icon:clear-day,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:43.44,apparentTemperature:39.64,dewPoint:21.12,humidity:0.41,pressure:1029.5,windSpeed:6.37,windGust:10.62,windBearing:192,cloudCover:0.02,uvIndex:3,visibility:10,ozone:337.1},{time:1617116400,summary:Clear,icon:clear-day,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:46.62,apparentTemperature:42.88,dewPoint:20.83,humidity:0.36,pressure:1029.2,windSpeed:7.49,windGust:12,windBearing:184,cloudCover:0.01,uvIndex:5,visibility:10,ozone:339.7},{time:1617120000,summary:Clear,icon:clear-day,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:49.25,apparentTemperature:45.64,dewPoint:22.44,humidity:0.35,pressure:1028.8,windSpeed:8.54,windGust:13.07,windBearing:183,cloudCover:0,uvIndex:6,visibility:10,ozone:334.3},{time:1617123600,summary:Clear,icon:clear-day,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:51.94,apparentTemperature:51.94,dewPoint:24.32,humidity:0.34,pressure:1028.6,windSpeed:9.59,windGust:14.25,windBearing:184,cloudCover:0,uvIndex:6,visibility:10,ozone:331.9},{time:1617127200,summary:Clear,icon:clear-day,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:54.11,apparentTemperature:54.11,dewPoint:26.09,humidity:0.34,pressure:1028.1,windSpeed:10.88,windGust:15.62,windBearing:184,cloudCover:0.01,uvIndex:5,visibility:10,ozone:329.5},{time:1617130800,summary:Clear,icon:clear-day,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:55.36,apparentTemperature:55.36,dewPoint:27.02,humidity:0.33,pressure:1027.5,windSpeed:12.13,windGust:17.43,windBearing:189,cloudCover:0.03,uvIndex:4,visibility:10,ozone:326.1},{time:1617134400,summary:Clear,icon:clear-day,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:55.51,apparentTemperature:55.51,dewPoint:27.83,humidity:0.34,pressure:1026.6,windSpeed:13,windGust:19.1,windBearing:193,cloudCover:0.05,uvIndex:3,visibility:10,ozone:324.8},{time:1617138000,summary:Clear,icon:clear-day,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:54.64,apparentTemperature:54.64,dewPoint:28.77,humidity:0.37,pressure:1026.1,windSpeed:13.46,windGust:20.86,windBearing:197,cloudCover:0.06,uvIndex:1,visibility:10,ozone:326.2},{time:1617141600,summary:Clear,icon:clear-day,precipIntensity:0,precipProbability:0,temperature:52.9,apparentTemperature:52.9,dewPoint:29.62,humidity:0.41,pressure:1026,windSpeed:13.3,windGust:23.12,windBearing:197,cloudCover:0.07,uvIndex:0,visibility:10,ozone:327}]},offset:-4} )
```

but I can't seem to access the "data" key

Comment: Please, update your question to add to output of `var_export($yourArray)`.

Comment: @Syscall, updated as requested.  How do I make this an associative array?

Comment: Why do you think that data are messy? Just put the value of the index 0 to the validator, and it's a 100% valid JSON string, which can be easily decoded into a PHP assoc array, like `json_decode($darkRaw[0], true)`. No need to strip any quotes manually, you damage the JSON data that way.

Comment: @biesior I tried that but it doesn't work.  When I try to print_r the decoded array I get nothing.

Comment: @DCR of course I tried it as well before posting, please check my answer. It does exactly what Christoff suggested at the very beginning, just with data included, to show you it just works. If for some reason it still gives you nothing, that means that you're doing some additional stuff which brokes the JSON decoding.

Comment: @biesior, it does work! The problem I was having was caused by removing all the quotes with str_replace.  When I skip that step it works as expected.  Thanks for your help

Comment: "**I told ya!**" :D, good that's work, go to next task :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the PHP function `json_decode` ([reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php))

It would convert your received JSON data into objects or an array.
eg.

```
$darkSkyData = json_decode($darkRaw);
echo 'Latitude is '.$darkSkyData->latitude;
```

If you set the 'associative' flag to TRUE you can work with an array instead, eg.

```
$darkSkyData = json_decode($darkRaw, true);
echo 'Latitude is '.$darkSkyData['latitude'];
```

Answer (score 1):

It does work, in case you didn't damage JSON data before. Note that **Christoff** already gave you a valid solution, just using another name for variables.

Fully, working sample.

```php
<?php

$darkRaw = [];
$darkRaw[] = '{"latitude":42.337,"longitude":-70.951589,"timezone":"America/New_York","hourly":{"summary":"Rain until tonight.","icon":"rain","data":[{"time":1616968800,"summary":"Rain","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0659,"precipProbability":0.66,"precipType":"rain","temperature":51.01,"apparentTemperature":51.01,"dewPoint":49.37,"humidity":0.94,"pressure":998.7,"windSpeed":15.22,"windGust":30.64,"windBearing":172,"cloudCover":1,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":2.07,"ozone":329.1},{"time":1616972400,"summary":"Possible Light Rain","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0263,"precipProbability":0.53,"precipType":"rain","temperature":53.33,"apparentTemperature":53.33,"dewPoint":50.86,"humidity":0.91,"pressure":997.2,"windSpeed":15.07,"windGust":34.46,"windBearing":196,"cloudCover":0.99,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":3.242,"ozone":332.5},{"time":1616976000,"summary":"Possible Light Rain","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0262,"precipProbability":0.51,"precipType":"rain","temperature":54.85,"apparentTemperature":54.85,"dewPoint":52.19,"humidity":0.91,"pressure":996.3,"windSpeed":15.46,"windGust":36.98,"windBearing":202,"cloudCover":1,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":7.329,"ozone":336.3},{"time":1616979600,"summary":"Possible Light Rain","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0281,"precipProbability":0.55,"precipType":"rain","temperature":56.53,"apparentTemperature":56.53,"dewPoint":53.96,"humidity":0.91,"pressure":995.5,"windSpeed":16.51,"windGust":38.82,"windBearing":207,"cloudCover":1,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":4.65,"ozone":338.7},{"time":1616983200,"summary":"Rain","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0385,"precipProbability":0.63,"precipType":"rain","temperature":57.18,"apparentTemperature":57.18,"dewPoint":54.59,"humidity":0.91,"pressure":994.9,"windSpeed":16.19,"windGust":35.72,"windBearing":235,"cloudCover":1,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":9.149,"ozone":341.9},{"time":1616986800,"summary":"Rain","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0938,"precipProbability":0.8,"precipType":"rain","temperature":56.45,"apparentTemperature":56.45,"dewPoint":52.95,"humidity":0.88,"pressure":995.3,"windSpeed":14.9,"windGust":31.54,"windBearing":260,"cloudCover":1,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":8.05,"ozone":344.8},{"time":1616990400,"summary":"Rain","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0635,"precipProbability":0.75,"precipType":"rain","temperature":54.37,"apparentTemperature":54.37,"dewPoint":49.05,"humidity":0.82,"pressure":995.7,"windSpeed":13.13,"windGust":28.63,"windBearing":245,"cloudCover":1,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":347.9},{"time":1616994000,"summary":"Rain","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0591,"precipProbability":0.69,"precipType":"rain","temperature":52.74,"apparentTemperature":52.74,"dewPoint":46.32,"humidity":0.79,"pressure":995.8,"windSpeed":13.41,"windGust":27.31,"windBearing":260,"cloudCover":0.99,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":355.4},{"time":1616997600,"summary":"Rain","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0428,"precipProbability":0.55,"precipType":"rain","temperature":50.68,"apparentTemperature":50.68,"dewPoint":43.09,"humidity":0.75,"pressure":996.1,"windSpeed":14.22,"windGust":28.9,"windBearing":257,"cloudCover":0.96,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":369.5},{"time":1617001200,"summary":"Possible Light Rain","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0346,"precipProbability":0.32,"precipType":"rain","temperature":49.72,"apparentTemperature":44,"dewPoint":40.71,"humidity":0.71,"pressure":996.4,"windSpeed":16.2,"windGust":33.27,"windBearing":272,"cloudCover":0.92,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":371.1},{"time":1617004800,"summary":"Mostly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-night","precipIntensity":0.0034,"precipProbability":0.14,"precipType":"rain","temperature":48.09,"apparentTemperature":41.5,"dewPoint":38.25,"humidity":0.69,"pressure":996.7,"windSpeed":18.05,"windGust":36.02,"windBearing":257,"cloudCover":0.71,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":386.4},{"time":1617008400,"summary":"Windy and Partly Cloudy","icon":"wind","precipIntensity":0.0013,"precipProbability":0.09,"precipType":"rain","temperature":46.03,"apparentTemperature":38.28,"dewPoint":35.67,"humidity":0.67,"pressure":997.2,"windSpeed":20.51,"windGust":39.58,"windBearing":261,"cloudCover":0.43,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":399.7},{"time":1617012000,"summary":"Windy and Partly Cloudy","icon":"wind","precipIntensity":0.0011,"precipProbability":0.07,"precipType":"rain","temperature":43.86,"apparentTemperature":35.16,"dewPoint":33.77,"humidity":0.67,"pressure":998.2,"windSpeed":21.81,"windGust":42.09,"windBearing":238,"cloudCover":0.35,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":408.5},{"time":1617015600,"summary":"Windy and Partly Cloudy","icon":"wind","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":42.2,"apparentTemperature":32.66,"dewPoint":31.89,"humidity":0.67,"pressure":999.6,"windSpeed":23.3,"windGust":42.52,"windBearing":300,"cloudCover":0.5,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":413.4},{"time":1617019200,"summary":"Windy and Partly Cloudy","icon":"wind","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":41.32,"apparentTemperature":31.37,"dewPoint":30.71,"humidity":0.66,"pressure":1001.5,"windSpeed":23.87,"windGust":42.91,"windBearing":270,"cloudCover":0.43,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":418.1},{"time":1617022800,"summary":"Windy and Partly Cloudy","icon":"wind","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":41.72,"apparentTemperature":31.89,"dewPoint":30.27,"humidity":0.64,"pressure":1002.7,"windSpeed":23.91,"windGust":43.93,"windBearing":229,"cloudCover":0.41,"uvIndex":1,"visibility":10,"ozone":420.2},{"time":1617026400,"summary":"Windy and Partly Cloudy","icon":"wind","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":42.74,"apparentTemperature":33.29,"dewPoint":29.96,"humidity":0.6,"pressure":1003.8,"windSpeed":23.75,"windGust":43.99,"windBearing":323,"cloudCover":0.35,"uvIndex":2,"visibility":10,"ozone":425},{"time":1617030000,"summary":"Windy and Partly Cloudy","icon":"wind","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":43.87,"apparentTemperature":34.87,"dewPoint":29.1,"humidity":0.56,"pressure":1005.1,"windSpeed":23.34,"windGust":43.12,"windBearing":279,"cloudCover":0.34,"uvIndex":3,"visibility":10,"ozone":424.2},{"time":1617033600,"summary":"Windy","icon":"wind","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":44.75,"apparentTemperature":36.1,"dewPoint":28.65,"humidity":0.53,"pressure":1006.4,"windSpeed":23,"windGust":41.05,"windBearing":275,"cloudCover":0.21,"uvIndex":4,"visibility":10,"ozone":424.4},{"time":1617037200,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":45.93,"apparentTemperature":37.74,"dewPoint":27.45,"humidity":0.48,"pressure":1007.8,"windSpeed":22.61,"windGust":38.93,"windBearing":278,"cloudCover":0.17,"uvIndex":4,"visibility":10,"ozone":425.8},{"time":1617040800,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":47.23,"apparentTemperature":39.59,"dewPoint":25.54,"humidity":0.42,"pressure":1009.5,"windSpeed":21.96,"windGust":36.83,"windBearing":288,"cloudCover":0.12,"uvIndex":4,"visibility":10,"ozone":430.4},{"time":1617044400,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":48.02,"apparentTemperature":40.82,"dewPoint":22.69,"humidity":0.37,"pressure":1010.7,"windSpeed":20.94,"windGust":35.26,"windBearing":292,"cloudCover":0.02,"uvIndex":3,"visibility":10,"ozone":427.7},{"time":1617048000,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":48.35,"apparentTemperature":41.48,"dewPoint":20.24,"humidity":0.33,"pressure":1012.2,"windSpeed":19.76,"windGust":34.55,"windBearing":296,"cloudCover":0.02,"uvIndex":2,"visibility":10,"ozone":423.5},{"time":1617051600,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":48.07,"apparentTemperature":41.42,"dewPoint":19.28,"humidity":0.32,"pressure":1013.9,"windSpeed":18.29,"windGust":33.4,"windBearing":299,"cloudCover":0.02,"uvIndex":1,"visibility":10,"ozone":417.6},{"time":1617055200,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":47.04,"apparentTemperature":40.48,"dewPoint":18.85,"humidity":0.32,"pressure":1015.7,"windSpeed":16.48,"windGust":32.14,"windBearing":298,"cloudCover":0.02,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":410.5},{"time":1617058800,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":45.48,"apparentTemperature":38.93,"dewPoint":18.44,"humidity":0.34,"pressure":1017.6,"windSpeed":14.7,"windGust":30.35,"windBearing":297,"cloudCover":0.02,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":405.2},{"time":1617062400,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":44.57,"apparentTemperature":38.23,"dewPoint":18.68,"humidity":0.35,"pressure":1019.8,"windSpeed":13.13,"windGust":28.3,"windBearing":297,"cloudCover":0,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":386.7},{"time":1617066000,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":43.55,"apparentTemperature":37.34,"dewPoint":18.82,"humidity":0.37,"pressure":1021.4,"windSpeed":11.88,"windGust":26.71,"windBearing":296,"cloudCover":0,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":383.1},{"time":1617069600,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":42.55,"apparentTemperature":36.45,"dewPoint":18.74,"humidity":0.38,"pressure":1022.7,"windSpeed":10.89,"windGust":24.83,"windBearing":294,"cloudCover":0,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":381.3},{"time":1617073200,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":41.59,"apparentTemperature":35.68,"dewPoint":18.43,"humidity":0.39,"pressure":1023.8,"windSpeed":9.83,"windGust":22.68,"windBearing":293,"cloudCover":0,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":377.2},{"time":1617076800,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":40.62,"apparentTemperature":34.99,"dewPoint":18.47,"humidity":0.41,"pressure":1024.4,"windSpeed":8.71,"windGust":20.42,"windBearing":296,"cloudCover":0,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":372.9},{"time":1617080400,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":39.59,"apparentTemperature":34.24,"dewPoint":18.72,"humidity":0.43,"pressure":1025.1,"windSpeed":7.71,"windGust":18.16,"windBearing":275,"cloudCover":0,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":367.9},{"time":1617084000,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":38.54,"apparentTemperature":33.49,"dewPoint":19.08,"humidity":0.45,"pressure":1025.4,"windSpeed":6.81,"windGust":15.13,"windBearing":287,"cloudCover":0.02,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":359.3},{"time":1617087600,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":37.52,"apparentTemperature":32.69,"dewPoint":19.2,"humidity":0.47,"pressure":1026,"windSpeed":6.17,"windGust":12.9,"windBearing":326,"cloudCover":0.03,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":353.7},{"time":1617091200,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":36.45,"apparentTemperature":31.56,"dewPoint":19.6,"humidity":0.5,"pressure":1026.8,"windSpeed":5.95,"windGust":12.48,"windBearing":212,"cloudCover":0.02,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":351.4},{"time":1617094800,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":35.68,"apparentTemperature":30.91,"dewPoint":20,"humidity":0.53,"pressure":1027.6,"windSpeed":5.61,"windGust":11.89,"windBearing":253,"cloudCover":0.01,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":349.2},{"time":1617098400,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":35.09,"apparentTemperature":30.39,"dewPoint":20.28,"humidity":0.54,"pressure":1028.1,"windSpeed":5.38,"windGust":11.72,"windBearing":265,"cloudCover":0.01,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":345.6},{"time":1617102000,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":35.21,"apparentTemperature":30.69,"dewPoint":20.67,"humidity":0.55,"pressure":1028.7,"windSpeed":5.19,"windGust":11.11,"windBearing":245,"cloudCover":0.01,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":341.4},{"time":1617105600,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":36.88,"apparentTemperature":32.89,"dewPoint":21.23,"humidity":0.53,"pressure":1029.6,"windSpeed":4.9,"windGust":8.38,"windBearing":229,"cloudCover":0.05,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":337.7},{"time":1617109200,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":39.87,"apparentTemperature":35.99,"dewPoint":21.09,"humidity":0.47,"pressure":1029.9,"windSpeed":5.44,"windGust":9,"windBearing":216,"cloudCover":0.04,"uvIndex":2,"visibility":10,"ozone":336.2},{"time":1617112800,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":43.3,"apparentTemperature":39.47,"dewPoint":21.12,"humidity":0.41,"pressure":1029.8,"windSpeed":6.37,"windGust":10.62,"windBearing":192,"cloudCover":0.02,"uvIndex":3,"visibility":10,"ozone":337.1},{"time":1617116400,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":46.47,"apparentTemperature":42.7,"dewPoint":20.86,"humidity":0.36,"pressure":1029.4,"windSpeed":7.49,"windGust":11.99,"windBearing":184,"cloudCover":0.01,"uvIndex":5,"visibility":10,"ozone":339.7},{"time":1617120000,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":49.16,"apparentTemperature":45.53,"dewPoint":22.48,"humidity":0.35,"pressure":1028.9,"windSpeed":8.52,"windGust":13.06,"windBearing":182,"cloudCover":0,"uvIndex":6,"visibility":10,"ozone":334.3},{"time":1617123600,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":51.86,"apparentTemperature":51.86,"dewPoint":24.33,"humidity":0.34,"pressure":1028.7,"windSpeed":9.6,"windGust":14.24,"windBearing":184,"cloudCover":0,"uvIndex":6,"visibility":10,"ozone":331.9},{"time":1617127200,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":54.05,"apparentTemperature":54.05,"dewPoint":26.09,"humidity":0.34,"pressure":1028.3,"windSpeed":10.88,"windGust":15.61,"windBearing":184,"cloudCover":0.01,"uvIndex":5,"visibility":10,"ozone":329.5},{"time":1617130800,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":55.34,"apparentTemperature":55.34,"dewPoint":26.99,"humidity":0.33,"pressure":1027.6,"windSpeed":12.12,"windGust":17.42,"windBearing":189,"cloudCover":0.03,"uvIndex":4,"visibility":10,"ozone":326.1},{"time":1617134400,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":55.49,"apparentTemperature":55.49,"dewPoint":27.83,"humidity":0.34,"pressure":1026.8,"windSpeed":13,"windGust":19.07,"windBearing":193,"cloudCover":0.05,"uvIndex":3,"visibility":10,"ozone":324.8},{"time":1617138000,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":54.56,"apparentTemperature":54.56,"dewPoint":28.77,"humidity":0.37,"pressure":1026.2,"windSpeed":13.46,"windGust":20.83,"windBearing":197,"cloudCover":0.06,"uvIndex":1,"visibility":10,"ozone":326.2},{"time":1617141600,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":52.82,"apparentTemperature":52.82,"dewPoint":29.61,"humidity":0.41,"pressure":1026.1,"windSpeed":13.3,"windGust":23.12,"windBearing":197,"cloudCover":0.07,"uvIndex":0,"visibility":10,"ozone":327}]},"offset":-4}';
$json = json_decode($darkRaw[0], true);

echo '<pre>';

echo 'access required keys only:' . PHP_EOL;
echo 'LAT: ' . $json['latitude'] . ', LON: ' . $json['longitude'];

echo PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
echo 'show whole array below...' . PHP_EOL;
print_r($json);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seem that your array contains JSON strings. You could use [`json_decode()`](https://php.net/json_decode). You can access to `data` key with `$data->hourly->data`:

```php
$array = [
    '{latitude:42.337,longitude:-70.951589,timezone:America/New_York,hourly:{summary:Rain until tonight.,icon:rain,data:[]}}',
];

foreach ($array as $row) {
    $data = json_decode($row);
    var_dump($data->hourly->data);
}
```